# Given the gradient of $f(x,y)$, prove that $f$ is unique up to a constant

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the gradient of $f(x,y)$, prove that $f$ is unique up to a constant term (assuming that $f$ exists for the given gradient). I assume this is true but I'm not very familiar with multivariable calculus. Please direct me to a proof (wikipedia or something).

Comment: You should also ask the gradient to be defined on a simply connected space

Comment: What does that mean?